# IOS Setting a variable from instance of included class into instance of class that includes it

Tags: ios, design-patterns, circular-dependency

I have two classes: `classA` and `ClassB`, now I have included Class B into Class A

So inside classA is written`#import "classB.h"`

Now, my question is how would you set a variable inside classA ***FROM A METHOD INSIDE*** classB, such that suppose A is an instance of classA, and B is an instance of classB and I say `A.var = self.var` in the method, suppose var are properties in both classes.

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating **ClassB** you can set the var from **ClassA**

```
ClassB *b = [[ClassB alloc]init];
b.var = self.var;
```

so from ClassB you can access the values like below

```
NSLog("%@",self.var)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either send a variable by reference to the method of B class or you can return an object from the function in classB and assign it to a variable in classA:

```
self.var=[classB func];
```

if func is a static function in class classB
or

```
self.var=[B func];
```

if func is a non-static function in class classB and B is an object of classB in classA

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the variable public, or make it into a property.  For example, to make it public:

```
@interface ClassA
{
@public
    int var;
}
// methods...
@end

// Inside a ClassB method:
ClassA *obj = ...;
obj->var = 3;
```

To make it a property:

```
@interface ClassA
{
    int var;  // @ this is protected by default
}
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) int var;
// methods...
@end

@implementation ClassA
@synthesize var;
...
@end

// In ClassB 
ClassA *obj = ...;
obj.var = 3;  // implicitly calls [obj setVar:3]
int x = obj.var;  // implicitly calls x = [obj var];
```